# Who are Edric Dayne's parents and how common it is for Lowborn Children to have Wet nurses?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Arya meets Ned, who is squire to Lord Beric Dondarrion.

> “Wylla was my wetnurse,” he repeated solemnly. “I swear it on the honor of my House.”
>
> “You have a House?” That was stupid; he was a squire, of course he had a House. “Who are you?”
>
> “I’m Edric Dayne, the... the Lord of Starfall.”
>
> “There was an Arthur Dayne,” Arya remembered. “The one they called the Sword of the Morning.”
>
> “My father was Ser Arthur’s elder brother. Lady Ashara was my aunt. I never knew her, though. She threw herself into the sea from atop the Palestone Sword before I was born.”

Here, Ned doesn't share his mother's name. Is it known?

> Arya had always heard that Dornishmen were small and swarthy, with black hair and small black eyes, but  Ned had big blue eyes, so dark that they looked almost purple. And his hair was a pale blond, more ash than honey.

Also, how common is it for children to have a wetnurse? Is it normal for highborn children, or only children without a mother?

Comment: Your real question seems to be "Who is Edric Dayne's mother?". Perhaps your question title should reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **We do not know who are Edric Dayne's parents yet**.

In the passage you cited, Edric does not mention his Father's name either. And that is the sole passage which is about Edric Dayne.

The only family tree for House Dayne which is canon [can be found here](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Dayne#House_Dayne_at_the_end_of_the_third_century).

[image]

As you can see, we do not know who are parents of Edric Dayne.

About your other question, Wet Nurse is not a luxury privilege. While in Canon sources, we know infants can be fed goat's or cow's milk if human milk is not available (See example of Mance Rayder's son and Craster's son). But it appears that Westerosi people generally prefer breastfeeding. But since Wet-nurses would require money, financial condition of the parent in question would matter here, not his social status. But this is only speculation because in canon sources we do not know anything about infancy of a Low-born orphan.

---